# Notify receivers when emails are rejected because of attachment size limits

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I've a size limit for attachments set in the Exchange Administration Console. The sender receives a NDR when the mail does not reach the intended recipients because of the size limit but can the recipients be notified of the same?

I've searched Microsoft's TechNet, SuperUser and SpiceWorks. The best solution from these is to let the sender notify the receiver, is there a better solution?

Comment: The Outlook client has a "how big is the quota" option ... why not using that?

Comment: @BastianW, The quota information in outlook does not show send/receive sizes as far as I understand but even if it did it would not notify my user that an email intended for him was rejected due to the quota limit.

Comment: I wasn´t exactly sure what you mean. The first idea was that an user send an email and added an attachment, which would be bigger than the allowed size. This should be shown in the Outlook client as an error message (see [here](https://www.msoutlook.info/pictures/attachmentsizewarning-2013.png)).

Comment: @BastianW, I have modified the question hopefully to rectify the confusion. I want the receiver to be notified, the sender gets a NDR anyway.